# phantom-html2pdf css not apply

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, html2pdf

try to convert html to pdf with phantom-html2pdf nodejs.everything working without problem except one. i try to apply CSS to my output but nothing happen at all.

```
    app.get("/ph2p", function(req, res) {
  var pdf = require("phantom-html2pdf");

  var fs = require("fs");

  fs.unlink("./file.pdf", function() {
    console.log("pdf file deleted!");
  });

  pdf.convert(
    {
      'html': "htmlfile.html",
      'css': "style.css",
      js: "",
      runnings: "",
      'paperSize': { format: "A4", orientation: "portrait", border: "1cm" },
      deleteOnAction: true,
      runningsArgs: ""
    },
    function(err, result) {
      result.toFile("file.pdf", function() {
        console.log("pdf file created");
      });
    }
  );

  res.end("pdf checking...");
});
```

anyone have clue what's wrong?

Comment: Are you certain that the css file is in the same directory as your js file? It could be a path issue. Use this to create the fully qualified path and see if it helps: `__dirname + '/style.css`

Comment: unfortunately not working.

Comment: Looking through the library code, it looks like it tries to take your CSS file and make a temporary CSS file from it. https://github.com/bauhausjs/phantom-html2pdf/blob/master/lib/phantom-html2pdf.js#L53 it looks like it throws some debugger logs to the console, are you seeing any of those? And if so, what do they say?

Comment: no error or anything in console.

Comment: What I might do then is go into your node modules folder that has that library installed, and either add your own `console.log` statements or put some breakpoints in there and try to step through those methods. Try to figure out where it's failing.